# Render CSV example for swashbuckle

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swashbuckle

I have an API that can return an csv or json, deppending on the `Accept` header mimetype.

I've decorated the method with `[Produces("application/json","text/csv")]`. Here it is a MRE with the ASP.NET Core default project:

```
public class WeatherForecast
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
}
```

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
[Produces("application/json","text/csv")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = "Freezing"
    })
    .ToArray();
}
```

This enables the mimetype selection in the Swagger UI, and it's being correct added to the `Accept` header of the request. My issue is that the example response value is not being formatted as csv, but as json.

[image: Example value for the csv mimetype]

How can I configure how examples are rendered for custom mimetypes, like text/csv?

I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore Version 6.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Examples` package.

And you can refer below post.

[Editing media type in Swagger with Swashbuckle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71382586/editing-media-type-in-swagger-with-swashbuckle)

Comment: With that I would have to create examples manually for each type of my schema? (PS: note that Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Examples is deprecated and was replaced by Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters)